# Logging with NxBRE

Tags: logging, nxbre

How do I instruct NxBRE engine to log some message? I know there is `<log>` tag available, which can be used as follows:

```
<Log level="INFO" msg="blabla"/>
```

But I cannot find any documentation on it. Mainly, I need answers to these questions:

1. How do I specify which logging engine to use (e.g., I want to use log4net - how do I let NxBRE know this)?
2. What are supported values of `level` attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NxBRE relies on `System.Diagnostics` for its logging needs, and therefore is configured via the standard .NET mechanism. This is documented in section 5 of the [user guide](https://github.com/ddossot/NxBRE/blob/master/Misc/NxBRE-Documentation-3_3_0.odt?raw=true), from which the following is taken:

> Here is the list of available sources and switches:
>
> Source / Switch Name | Purpose
>
> NxBRE.FlowEngine | Trace events emitted by the Flow Engine.
>
> NxBRE.FlowEngine.RuleBase | Trace events emitted by rule base level operations (log, exceptions).
>
> NxBRE.InferenceEngine | Trace events emitted by the Inference Engine.
> NxBRE.Util | Trace events emitted by the utility classes.

If you want to use log4net, you will have to fork the project and switch to this logging framework.

Comment: Thanks, David. Could you please share a link to the full user guide?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/ddossot/NxBRE/blob/master/Misc/NxBRE-Documentation-3_3_0.odt?raw=true